# Detect document or picture from a set of images in java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I have a set of images, I want to detect that the image is document or picture.
My first approach is to detect the pixel color, if the image has back and white color, then its a document other wise Image, but its not very efficient, because the set may contain clip art or other back and white image.

So I'm searching for a white paper or algorithm, through which i can detect that image is document or picture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all your files provided as image files? Otherwise you could simply checking the mime type

Comment: Yes all the files are image.

Comment: You could try to identify characters using OCR

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j